# JWT tokens for Single Sign On on Azure AD

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services

Is there a way to get a JWT token for federated single sign on in Azure AD instead of the currently configurable SAML2 tokens?

I can see 

`FEDERATION METADATA DOCUMENT
WS-FEDERATION SIGN-ON ENDPOINT
SAML-P SIGN-ON ENDPOINT
SAML-P SIGN-OUT ENDPOINT
MICROSOFT AZURE AD GRAPH API ENDPOINT
OAUTH 2.0 TOKEN ENDPOINT
OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT`

endpoints in my test Azure AD tenant.
But I don't see any JWT-based for Single Sign On (not OAuth2).

Does that mean that Azure AD doesn't support JWT in federated Single Sign On scenarios?
(I've tried to search their docs but only found JWT mentions in the OAuth2 flows)

Answer (score 0):

After almost a year after this question, I still have not found a way to generate JWT token in MS Azure AD.

I have successfully used the existing SAML2 option.

Comment: Hi Sergey, do you have an article with steps on how to configure Angular Apps for SSO using SAML?